# Random number generator: counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, counter

I have this random number generator to record the positive, negative and zeroes recorded by the random generator. But, when I test it the negative numbers aren't recorded and are instead recorded in the positive counter. I don't see whats wrong with my code, any assistance?

```
from random import randint
posi_counter = 0
nega_counter = 0
zero_counter = 0
avg_counter = 0

# Inputs
num_gen = int(input("How many numbers to be generated? "))
if num_gen > 0:
    max_gen = int(input("Enter maximum number to be generated (>0): "))
    min_gen = max_gen * -1
    print("For {} numbers in the range, {} to {}:".format(
    num_gen, min_gen, max_gen))
    avg = 0
    # Outputs
    for x in range(num_gen):
        print(randint(min_gen, max_gen))
        avg_counter += 1
        avg = avg + x
        if x > 0:
            posi_counter += 1
        elif x < 0:
            nega_counter += 1
        elif x == 0:
            zero_counter += 1
    average_total = avg / avg_counter
    print("{} positive numbers".format(posi_counter))
    print("{} zero numbers".format(zero_counter))
    print("{} negative numbers".format(nega_counter))
    print("{:.1f} average value".format(average_total))
```

Comment: `x`, due to `range(num_gen)` is always positive. You aren't retaining the value generated from `randint`.

Comment: As an aside, I would rename your `avg` variable to `total`.  (It's not the average of the random variables, it's their sum - but `sum` is a python builtin, so would be a bad choice of name.  `average_total` could then become `average`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` comes from `range(num_gen)`, so it is always `>= 0`, do something like this instead:

```
for _ in range(num_gen):
    x = randint(min_gen, max_gen)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Ahh I see  I definitely learned more about the for loop today. Thanks